# Java to MIPS Add array

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

Using a loop i need to convert `sum[i] = sum[i-1] + array[i]` to MIPS here is the code I have already:

```
# initialise array
.text
main:
    la $t0,array
    la $t1,sum

    li $s2,1
    li $s4,20       

loop:   
    bgt $s2, $s4, end

    sw $s2,0($t0)
    addi $s2, $s2, 1
    addi $t0, $t0, 4    

    add $s2, $s4, $s3

    j loop

end:
    li $v0,10
    syscall

.data
nl:      .asciiz "\n" .word 255
array:   .space 80
sum:     .space 80
```

I have started the sum array but do not know where to go from here any hints will be great.

Comment: What's the problem with your code? What's not working?

Comment: Well, that would involve two loads and a store. Currently you only have a store, and it's to the wrong location (`array[i]`).

Comment: I'd recommend posting the java code as the initial conditions aren't clear. That is, what is the initial value for `i`? If it's zero, we'd be fetching `sum[-1]`. Or do you mean `sum[i] = sum[i] + array[i]`? In addition to some logic bugs, your program aborts on an alignment exception. All this is fixable, but it would help for you to edit your post [to see your exact intent] before I post an answer.